# botman chatbot error 404 page not found in chat widget

Tags: php, laravel-5, chatbot, botman

I developed a chatbot using `botman` framework and it's working fine on localhost. After uploading it on cpanel chat widget gives an error of `404 page not found`. Can anyone please help me regarding this I am not able to find the solution.
Here you can see the error https://abhishekjaiswal.in/

`routes/botman.php`

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\BotManController;
use App\Conversations;

$botman = resolve('botman');

$botman->hears('hi|hello|good morning', 
BotManController::class.'@startConversation');

$botman->hears('Who are you', function($bot) {
$bot->reply('I am a chatbot');
});

$botman->hears('ok|okay|hmm|great', BotManController::class.'@KnowMore');

$botman->fallback(function($bot) {
$bot->reply('Sorry, I did not understand what you saying. Dont feel embarass just 
start with hi.');
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: where is your botman code resides? Is it in the same domain. show me your `routes/botman.php`, `routes/web.php` and folder structure of website

Comment: this is because it can't find the connection to your botman.php file. You have to make sure it is pointed at the correct chat server file

Comment: like @RohanKhude said. Some code and folder structure would help

Comment: The link you have provided takes people to your personal profile page. There does not seem to be anything relating to this question on that site.

Comment: @RohanKhude Yes it is in the same domain

Comment: information you provided is not enough to resolve the question. please post the code as well

Comment: are you using botman studio or installed botman in existing project?

Comment: I am using botman studio

Comment: frameEndpoint: '/botman/chat',chatServer : '/botman', I am having these two in my script tag

Comment: `https://abhishekjaiswal.in/routes/botman.php` (or `/web.php`) gives us your routes files. I'm expecting to have something here: https://abhishekjaiswal.in/public but it's a 404 error page. I think we are missing information